# While there are no MQL4 errors, why there was no GUI drawing produced?

Tags: mql4

For a learning purpose, I am trying to code a simple MA indicator that changes color when price crosses. Though there are no errors, it draws nothing. Could you review the attached code to show me my mistake?

```
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 2

extern int    maperiod = 20;
extern int    maprice  = PRICE_CLOSE;
extern int    mamethod = MODE_SMA;
extern color  colorup  = Green;
extern color  colordn  = Red;

       double mamain[];
       double bufferup[];
       double bufferdn[];
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int init(){
//--- indicator buffers mapping
   SetIndexBuffer( 0, bufferup );
   SetIndexStyle(  0, DRAW_LINE, 0, 2, colorup );
   SetIndexBuffer( 1, bufferdn );
   SetIndexStyle(  1, DRAW_LINE, 0, 2, colordn );
//---
   return( 0 );
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int start(){
//---
   int counted_bars = IndicatorCounted();
   if ( counted_bars < 0 ) return( -1 );
   if ( counted_bars > 0 ) counted_bars--;
   int limit = Bars - counted_bars;
   for (   int i = limit; i >= 0 ; i-- )
   {    mamain[i]  = iMA(    NULL, 0, maperiod, 0, 0, 0, i );
   if ( mamain[i] >= iClose( NULL, 0, i ) ) bufferup[i] = mamain[i];
   if ( mamain[i] <= iClose( NULL, 0, i ) ) bufferdn[i] = mamain[i];
   }
//--- return value of prev_calculated for next call
   return( 0 );
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### "Old"-MQL4 may work for some time, but still, get used to new features:

```
extern ENUM_APPLIED_PRICE MAprice  = PRICE_CLOSE; // AVOIDS incompatible values
extern ENUM_MA_METHOD     MAmethod = MODE_SMA;    // AVOIDS incompatible values
#define                   MAshift     0           // ADDS   code == intent match-robustness
extern int                MAperiod = 20;
extern color              colorUP  =  clrGreen;
extern color              colorDN  =  clrRed;

       double             bufferUP[];
       double             bufferDN[];

int init(){
    ArrayInitialize    bufferUP,  EMPTY_VALUE );
    SetIndexBuffer( 0, bufferUP );
    SetIndexStyle(  0, DRAW_LINE, EMPTY, 2, colorUP );
    SetIndexLabel(  0, "MA_ABOVE_Close" );

    ArrayInitialize    bufferDN,  EMPTY_VALUE );
    SetIndexBuffer( 1, bufferDN );
    SetIndexStyle(  1, DRAW_LINE, EMPTY, 2, colorDN );
    SetIndexLabel(  1, "MA_UNDER_Close" );

    return( 0 );
}

int start(){
    int  counted_bars = IndicatorCounted();
    if ( counted_bars < 0 ) return( -1 );
    if ( counted_bars > 0 ) counted_bars--;

    for ( int    i = Bars - counted_bars; i >= 0 ; i-- ){
          double C = iClose( _Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT, i ),
                 A = iMA(    _Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT,
                                      MAperiod,
                                      MAshift,
                                      MAmethod,
                                      MAprice,
                                      i
                                      );
          if ( A >= C ) bufferUP[i] = A;
          if ( A <= C ) bufferDN[i] = A;
    }
    return( 0 );
}
```

### *New*-MQL4.56789 uses another call-signature if **`#property strict`**:

```
int OnCalculate( const int       rates_total,
                 const int       prev_calculated,
                 const datetime &time_______ARR[],
                 const double   &open_______ARR[],
                 const double   &high_______ARR[],
                 const double   &low________ARR[],
                 const double   &close______ARR[],
                 const long     &tick_volumeARR[],
                 const long     &volume_____ARR[],
                 const int      &spread_____ARR[]
                 ){
//--- the main loop of calculations 
   for( int i  = prev_calculated - 1;
         (  i <  rates_total
         &&     !IsStopped() );          // AVOID SHARED (!) solo-THREAD BLOCKING
            i++
        ){
     // -----------------------------------------------------------------
          double A = iMA(    _Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT,
                                      MAperiod,
                                      MAshift,
                                      MAmethod,
                                      MAprice,
                                      i
                                      );
          if ( A >= close______ARR[i] ) bufferUP[i] = A;
          if ( A <= close______ARR[i] ) bufferDN[i] = A;
     // -----------------------------------------------------------------
   }
   return( rates_total );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your buffer **`mamain[]`** is not initialized.

```
int init(){

    IndicatorBuffers(3);
    SetIndexBuffer(2,mamain);
}
```

`rates_total` and `prev_calculated` seems preferred but of course you can use `IndicatorCounted()` but keep in mind the corner situation with the first bar: when you first attach the indicator to the chart, your `counted_bars` = 0 and `limit` = `Bars`, but `mamain[]` and other indicator buffers have `Bars` elements only, from 0 to `Bars-1`. so better to use
`int limit = Bars - counted_bars - 1;`

About resolving issues - in addition to asking here you can always try to attach your indicator to a chart and see it there's no error (terminal window - Experts folder), that will make delevopment faster

Comment: and also not clear whether you need to show buffers:) - add `#property indicator_buffers 2`